# Proving an existence using mean value theorem.

Tags: calculus, problem-solving

**Exact statement of problem from the book:**

If $0<a<b<(π/2)$, using Cauchy's mean value theorem, prove that $(\sin(a) - \sin(b))/(\cos(b) - \cos(a)) = \cot(x)$ for some $x$ in  $(a,b)$.

**My main Approach:**

I defined two functions $f(x)= \sin x $, and $g(x) = \cos x$.
Then since both the functions were differentiable in the interval $(a,b)$, I applied the mean value theorem to $f$ and $g$ to get:

$(\sin(a) - \sin(b))/(a-b) = \cos(c)$ for some $c$ in $(a,b)$. And,

$(\cos(b) - \cos(a))/(a-b) = \sin(d)$ for some $d$ in $(a,b)$.

Now if $c$ was equal to $d$, the problem would have been super easy, however since it wasn't, I tried to get some kind of relationship between $c$ and $d$ by solving for $a-b$ on both equations and equating the results, but that didn't end well.

**Question:**

How to solve the above stated problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

Consider the function
$$f(x)=\sin x-\sin b-\frac{\sin a-\sin b}{\cos a-\cos b}\,(\cos x-\cos b).$$
What are $f(a)$ and $f(b)$?

Comment: Ok, now the question is solved, but how does one even come up with the special function required? the function you gave seemed magically well suited to the problem...

Comment: You mean $f(x)$? It's adapted from the standard proof of *Cauchy's mean value theorem*, which itself is adapted from the formula for the equation of the line through two points.